# How to add comments on a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Rails and I try to add a comment function.

I have this error when I try to add a comment:
**No route matches [POST] "/advertisements/1"**

How can I say to Rails : "Hey dude, I would like you go to my comments#create function"

```
#app/views/advertisements/show.html.erb
<% if @current_user %>
    <%= render "comments/form", comment: @comment %>
<% end %>
```

```
#app/views/comments/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: comment, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.hidden_field :advertisement_id, :value => @advertisement.id %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :user_id, :advertisement_id)
    end
end
```

HTML form rendered (why he has "/advtertisements/1" in action input

```
<form action="/advertisements/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="pJOwu9LyhQmj4uSYhyeBKD66Zab+kJf9bR1m+eJJ1Fj+kznMl/4rVz69ucPa2gkuOc/yUB8rPLWhpH+6GHWaqQ==" />

  <div class="field">
    <textarea name="content" id="content">
</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input value="1" type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input value="1" type="hidden" name="advertisement_id" id="advertisement_id" />
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save " data-disable-with="Save " />
  </div>
</form>
```

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :advertisements
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create] do
    collection do
      get :login, to: 'sessions#new', as: "login"
      post :login, to: 'sessions#create'
      delete :logout, to: 'sessions#destroy', as: "logout"
    end
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

```
#app/controllers/advertisements_controller.rb
before_action :set_advertisement, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

...

# GET /advertisements/1
# GET /advertisements/1.json
def show
  @comments = @advertisement.comments.all
end

...

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_advertisement
  @advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
end
```

I know hidden_fields and form like mine are probably not the best option to do this kind of thing btw but I'm still learning. Thank you for your help !

Comment: What's the form HTML that is getting rendered?

Comment: Please share your routes.rb, that would be helpful

Comment: Could you also add code of advertisements controller(especially show method and code/methods related to it)?

Comment: Don't see any reference for `@comment` that is used in `render "comments/form", comment: @comment`. Do you happen to see if it is a proper comment object?

Answer (score 0):

### Why didn't my original code work?

The most likely cause is that you're passing the wrong thing to the partial. Passing an instance of Advertisement would cause the form to use the path `/advertisements/1`.

### What a better solution?

Start by a creating [nested route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :advertisements do
  resources :comments, shallow: true
end
```

This lets you create comments for a specific advertisements by sending a POST request to:

```
POST /advertisements/:advertisements_id/comments
```

You can setup the form to post to the nested route by passing an array:

```
#app/views/comments/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: [local_assigns[:advertisement], comment], local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Using `local_assigns(:advertisement)` lets you use the same partial for nested and non-nested views (edit/update) without risking a NoMethod error if its not passed. The array is compacted so a nil won't matter.

And then setup your controller so that it uses `params[:advertisement_id]` which will be passed as part of the request path and gets the user id from the session instead.

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # callbacks help you avoid duplication
  before_action :set_advertisement, only: [:new, :create, :index]

  # GET /advertisements/1/comments/new
  def new
    @comment = @advertisement.comments.new
  end

  # POST /advertisements/1/comments
  def create
    @comment = @advertisement.comments.new(comment_params) do |c|
      c.user = current_user # here I'm assuming you have a method that fetches the user from the session
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end

    def set_advertisement
      @advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:advertisement_id])
    end
end
```

Make sure you're rendering the partial correctly:

```
<%= render 'comments/form', advertisement: @advertisement, comment: @comment %>
```

To link to the "new" action you can use:

```
<%= link_to "Add a comment", new_advertisement_comment_path(@advertisement) %>
```

Comment: I get undefined method `local_assigns'. Do I have some gems to install ? local_assigns is a native rail helper ?

Comment: Thats really strange. It is a native helper. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html

Comment: Sorry my. Bad `local_assigns` is a hash and not a method. It should read `local_assigns[:advertisement]`.